# TypeError: room.map is not a function : ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function

I am currently using `ReactJs` to make a chat system that allows some African students to be able to speak about mental health issues with one another in an anonymous environment. I have a little name input, and I'm currently trying to create a select option so that these topics can show up, and can be filtered on the chat system, but I'm having a hard time getting it to actually render, it keeps crashing and saying **TypeError: room.map is not a function**.

```
const [room, setRoom] = useState([
    { label: "Depression", value: "Depression" },
    { label: "Anxiety", value: "Anxiety" },
    { label: "Chat", value: "Chat" }
  ]);

<select className="joinInput mt-20"  onChange={(event) => setRoom(event.currentTarget.value)}>
        {room.map(rooms => (
        <option
          key={rooms.value}
          value={rooms.value}
        >
          {rooms.label}
        </option>
          ))}
          </select>
```

Comment: why are you calling `setRoom` with `event.currentTarget.value` in your `onChange`? This will replace your `room` array of options with a single one, causing the error you've noticed. Whatever action you want to take when a new option is selected, it probably shouldn't affect the `room` array at all.

Comment: You're very correct, thank you. I'm quite new into ReactJS and Javascript, and arrays are something I'm still trying to understand. I changed it, and it helped thank you Robin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```js
const [currentRoom, setCurrentRoom] = useState()
const [room] = useState([
  { label: "Depression", value: "Depression" },
  { label: "Anxiety", value: "Anxiety" },
  { label: "Chat", value: "Chat" },
]);

return (
  <select
    className="joinInput mt-20"
    onChange={(event) => setCurrentRoom(event.currentTarget.value)}
    value={currentRoom}
    >
    <option value="">Select value...</option>
    {room.map((rooms) => (
      <option key={rooms.value} value={rooms.value}>
        {rooms.label}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
);
```